# Why does this python autobahn code need to use the 'yield' keyword?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, autobahn

Why does this python autobahn example code uses `yield sleep(1)` and not simply`sleep(1)` ?

```
class Component(ApplicationSession):
       """
   An application component that publishes an event every second.
   """

   @inlineCallbacks
   def onJoin(self, details):
      print("session attached")
      counter = 0
      while True:
         print(".")
         self.publish('com.myapp.topic1', counter)
         counter += 1
         yield sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   from autobahn.twisted.wamp import ApplicationRunner
   runner = ApplicationRunner("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws", "realm1")
   runner.run(Component)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Python's standard library `sleep` will block the Twisted reactor, whereas Autobahn's `sleep` helper for Twisted will return a Twisted Deferred (and not block the reactor): https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/autobahn/autobahn/twisted/util.py#L29

Comment: Thanks. I think you got the right answer. Changed my choice of answer. But this is scary. How would I know my other python code wouldn't end up blocking Twister?

Comment: You have to know what parts of the Python standard library are doing blocking syscalls under the hood. Essentially, everything network related in the stdlib is blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Using `yield sleep(1)` can return a result and do other things.

But using simply `sleep(1)` will cause `main` always in function `onJoin`.
It's a deadless loop.

Click [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr)

> The yield expression is only used when defining a generator function, and can only be used in the body of a function definition. Using a yield expression in a function definition is sufficient to cause that definition to create a generator function instead of a normal function.
>
> When a generator function is called, it returns an iterator known as a generator. That generator then controls the execution of a generator function. The execution starts when one of the generator’s methods is called. At that time, the execution proceeds to the first yield expression, where it is suspended again, returning the value of expression_list to generator’s caller. By suspended we mean that all local state is retained, including the current bindings of local variables, the instruction pointer, and the internal evaluation stack. When the execution is resumed by calling one of the generator’s methods, the function can proceed exactly as if the yield expression was just another external call. The value of the yield expression after resuming depends on the method which resumed the execution.
>
> All of this makes generator functions quite similar to coroutines; they yield multiple times, they have more than one entry point and their execution can be suspended. The only difference is that a generator function cannot control where should the execution continue after it yields; the control is always transferred to the generator’s caller.

Comment: Thanks. But why not `return sleep(1)`?

Comment: `return sleep(1)` terminates the `while` loop.